# What's the difference of listA.append(listB[:]) and listA.append(listB)?

Tags: python, list

Tried python 3 backtracking in leetcode. For the code below, ans.append(stack[:]) works but ans.append(stack) not.

Thanks in advance.

Leetcode.

```
def combine(self, n, k):
    """
    :type n: int
    :type k: int
    :rtype: List[List[int]]
    """
    nums = list(range(1,n+1))
    ans = []
    stack = []

    def backtracking( current_pos = 0, current_in_tuple = 0, rest = n):
        if current_in_tuple == k:
            ans.append(stack)
            return
        if rest + current_in_tuple < k:
            return

        for i in range(current_pos, n-k+current_in_tuple+1):
            stack.append(nums[i])
            backtracking(i+1, current_in_tuple+1, rest-1)
            stack.pop()


    backtracking()

    return ans
```

Input: 4,2

```
Actual:[[],[],[],[],[],[]]
Expected:[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]]
```

Comment: You need to give more relevant code. Are these functions part of a class? Where is stack created?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some hints to debug it, `stack[:]` creates a new array while `stack` refers to the same array you can check it with comparing the `id` of both see the point to a different location in memory

```
In [1]: a=[1,2,3]

In [2]: id(a)
Out[2]: 139944147306568

In [3]: id(a[:])
Out[3]: 139944156641672
```

You can see that in the below example what actually happens inside your result array

```
In [4]: b=[]

In [5]: b.append(a)

In [6]: b
Out[6]: [[1, 2, 3]]

In [7]: a[0]=400

In [8]: b
Out[8]: [[400, 2, 3]]
```

Notice that `b` gets modified after you modify `a` thats why the code gets wrong output

I hope you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `listA.append(listB)` adds a *shallow copy* of listB to listA, meaning that if listB is subsequently changed (i.e. by calling `listB.pop())`, that change will also happen in listA.

But `listA.append(listB[:])` makes a fully independent copy, with no linkage back to the original listB.

Comment: Thank you so much! Copy by reference!